# Is it a good practice to use foreach for multiple insertions on a database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a message and many recipients, what I want to know is when I want to save it.. is it good to use Statement.execute() for each recipient that the message have or it could be considered like "hard-coding"

```
   public void save(Int id,String subject, String body, ArrayList<String> emails){

    String sq = "CALL saveMessage(?,?)";
    CallableStatement st = this.connection.prepareCall(sq);
    st.setInt(1,id);
    st.setString(2, subject);
    st.setString(3, body);
    st.execute();

    for(String e:emails){

       query = "CALL saveRecipientByMessage(?,?)";
       CallableStatement st2 = this.connection.prepareCall(query);
       st2.setInt(1,id);
       st2.setString(2,e);
       st2.execute();
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm wondering - what else you could use except for?

Comment: Are you asking if it would be better to insert all the recipients into the db w/one insertion compared to a single insertion per recipient?

Comment: Commenting instead of answering since this is a bit out of my realm, but I think you could prepare the statement and probably set the ID before the loop rather than inside the loop. Otherwise I think it should be good.

Comment: In the first call, you're binding three variables but the query only has two placeholders; is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes. My mistake, actually the ID on the database is auto increment, but I did this example just to ask here. So.. I have to insert the message on the table first, and then with the ID of that message insert the recipients on an intermediate table. I don't know if there is any other way to handle this..

Comment: Hint: Prepare once outside the loop, execute multiple times *within* the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` is OK but the better JDBC practice here would be to use a batch.